# Error: (Internal server error) Django apache2 - mod_wsgi

Tags: django, ubuntu, apache2, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to deploy my django application on my remote server, but I'm getting an http 500 internal server error.
Here are the configurations I made:
**Structure file**

```
/home/ubuntu/project/env (virtualenv folder)
bin
include
lib

/home/ubuntu/project/
  |- manage.py
  | - env
  | - my_project

/home/ubuntu/project/my_project
    |__init__.py
    |settings.py
    |urls.py
    |wsgi.py
```

**Fichier 000-default.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    WSGIDaemonProcess myproject python-home=/home/ubuntu/project/env python- 
    path=/home/ubuntu/project/my_project
    WSGIProcessGroup myproject
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/project/my_project/wsgi.py

    <Directory /home/ubuntu/project/my_project>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**Error log**

```
  [Fri Dec 30 11:28:18.988904 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 31289:tid 140473618372288] [remote 
  41.82.143.41:50428]   File "/home/ubuntu/project/my_project/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
  [Fri Dec 30 11:28:18.988915 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 31289:tid 140473618372288] [remote 
  41.82.143.41:50428]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
  [Fri Dec 30 11:28:18.988933 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 31289:tid 140473618372288] [remote 
  41.82.143.41:50428] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
  [Fri Dec 30 11:28:19.164861 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 31289:tid 140473651943104] [remote 
  41.82.143.41:50427] mod_wsgi (pid=31289): Failed to exec Python script file 
  '/home/ubuntu/project/my_project/wsgi.py'.
  [Fri Dec 30 11:28:19.164958 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 31289:tid 140473651943104] [remote 
  41.82.143.41:50427] mod_wsgi (pid=31289): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 
 '/home/ubuntu/project/my_project/wsgi.py'.
 [Fri Dec 30 11:28:19.165130 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 31289:tid 140473651943104] [remote 
 41.82.143.41:50427] Traceback (most recent call last):
 [Fri Dec 30 11:28:19.165172 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 31289:tid 140473651943104] [remote 
 41.82.143.41:50427]   File "/home/ubuntu/project/my_project/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
 [Fri Dec 30 11:28:19.165183 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 31289:tid 140473651943104] [remote 
 41.82.143.41:50427]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
 [Fri Dec 30 11:28:19.165212 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 31289:tid 140473651943104] [remote 
 41.82.143.41:50427] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
```

I then used this process : make custom versions of Python and mod_wsgi ourselves.

```
apt install apache2 apache2-dev
wget https://codeload.github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/tar.gz/4.9.4
tar xvfz 4.9.4
cd mod_wsgi-4.9.4

./configure --with-python=[your python path]
## For example: ./configure --with-python=/usr/bin/python3.10

sudo make
sudo make install

## Finally:
sudo systemctl reload apache2
```

I use python 3.10 and apache2
and the error still persists (500 internal server error)
I do not know what to do ???

Comment: Hi @Pathia Nanto, Can you provide us with some file structure for your deployment?

Comment: Can you verify that the package `django` is installed in your virtualenv: `/home/ubuntu/project/env` ?

Comment: @programmeur_asservi , ok i added it to the post

Comment: @Alexandre , when I on the project folder and I run the command which django , I have nothing in return

Comment: Can you activate your virtualenv and execute the command `django-admin --version` and say what the output is?

Comment: @Alexandre , I get : 4.1.4

Comment: on my env folder, I don't see the django folder ????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by adding to my `wsgi.py` file the path where django is installed